# Android canvas scale, translate and positing

Tags: android, canvas

I'm trying the moving limit after zoom with canvas scale, but new coordinates does not match.
my width 480, after 1.5f zooming my width will be 720... but when I set translate to -480, I'm seeing more space on the right.

```
float zoom = 0.5f;
PointF translate = new PointF(0, 0);
canvas.scale(zoom, zoom);
canvas.translate(translate.x, translate.y);
//...
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);
```

sorry my bad English and explanation, but I want to ask in summary;
what is the true width/height limit for translate after zooming for moving the canvas?

Comment: Have you solved??..please share it..I am facing this problem.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem as follows;

(screen resolution: 800x480 [landscape])

```
int screenWidth = 800;
int gameLimitX = 1600;
int cameraPositionX = 0;

float zoom = 1.0;

if((screenWidth / zoom) + cameraPositionX > gameLimitX) {
    cameraPositionX = (screenWidth / zoom) + cameraPositionX;
}
```

(do same for y/height)
I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your current zoom and then multiply translations like this:

```
canvas.scale(_factorScale, _factorScale);
int wGameView = (int) (_wGameView/_factorScale);
int hGameView = (int) (_hGameView/_factorScale);
int xCam = (int) (ptCentre.x-(wGameView>>>1));
int yCam = (int) (ptCentre.y-(hGameView>>>1));
//move camera now!
canvas.translate(-xCam,-yCam);
//here goes drawing
```

Comment: I can't understand. what is mean ptCentre?