# Android view draw to bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

It most like this question:[How to convert View to Bitmap in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855087/how-to-convert-view-to-bitmap-in-android).
And my way is:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
int viewWidth = view.getWidth();
int viewHeight = view.getHeight();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth, viewHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);
return bitmap;
```

But there's a OutofMemory may happen in `createBitmap()`, so I want to scale the bitmap's size. Like this:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(viewWidth / 4, viewHeight / 4, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
```

Now the question is:

How can I draw view to the scaled bitmap?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you specify the value of `viewWidth` and `viewHeight`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of view is that? is it larger than the screen? From my experience there should be enough memory available to create a buffer the size of the screen. Did you check if there are other leaks in your app? Try to analyze your memory usage with the Android Device Monitor. As a last resort try to do a garbage collection System.gc() before allocating the bitmap.

Comment: The view is not larger than screen.Because I had filter this. 'If the view's is larger than screen, return null direct".

Comment: If you really have no memory (what I would investigate) and to answer the question how to scale the view to the bitmap: Use the Canvas translate and scale methods. See related [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198088/android-canvas-scale-translate-and-positing)

Comment: Thank you.There is a memory leak in my app.

Comment: cool so no need for scaling any more? please mark the answer as correct if this is the case